# Speeding up a MySql DELETE that relies on a BIT column

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb, sql-delete, bit

I’m using MySql 5.5.46 and have an InnoDB table with a Bit Column (named “ENABLED”).  There is no index on this column.  The table has 26 million rows, so understandably, the statement

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE ENABLED = 0;
```

takes a really long time.  My question is, is there anything I can do (without upgrading MySQL, which is not an option at this time), to speed up the time it takes to run this query?  My “innodb_buffer_pool_size” variable is set to the following:

```
show variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
+-------------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name           | Value       |
+-------------------------+-------------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 11674845184 |
+-------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: What do you mean by upgrading mysql (upgrade mysql or schema index creation, update?)

If not upgrade, why don't you index the column with bitmap index.

Comment: By "upgrade" I mean use a higher version of MySql (e.g. "6.1.0").

Comment: I would create a bitmap index, 26 millions rows is still pretty hefty for MYSQL and will still take a little while, but should speed up a lot.

Comment: THis feature isn't available thouhg in the version of MySQL that I use, though, right?  At lesat, this fails -- "CREATE BITMAP INDEX ON my_table (ENABLED);".

Comment: Yeah you're right, doesn't look like BITMAP is available on 5.5. Alternatively you could try a BTREE, will take more space but will speed up your query still. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html

Answer (score 0):

Do the `DELETE` in "chunks" of 1000, based on the `PRIMARY KEY`.  See [*Delete Big*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig).  That article goes into details about efficient ways to chunk, and what to do about gaps in the PK.

(With that 11GB buffer_pool, I assume you have 16GB of RAM?)

In general, MySQL will do a table scan instead of using an index if the number of rows to be selected is more than about 20% of the total number of rows.  Hence, almost never are "flag" fields worth indexing by themselves.

Comment: I recommend you all peruse Rick's articles. Good stuff on indexing and partitions